# Can we use Lightning Out and Canvas?

Tags: canvas, heroku, lightning-out

I'm wondering if the following is possible.

1. I have an aspx application (App1) that I currently access in SF using Canvas
2. I want to create a Lightning Component that contains that app (lightning:canvas component) - this seems to work
3. I then want to use Lightning Out to display App1 inside of a node.js Heroku hosted site

The lightning out piece seems to work but the canvas is empty.  It seems to be looking for salesforce canvas files inside the heroku domain.  So something like https://herokuapp.com/salesforcecanvascore.js which doesn't exist.

I'm just wondering if it is possible or if I missed something.

Comment: I have come across this issue recently, can you let me know if you are mentioning the attribute called containerid in the force:canvasApp ?? If so can you try to remove that check for the behavior ( most probably it will not work ) however there were some claims that this was causing the issue . Though this did not work for me.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that suggestion as well.  It did help with the basic canvas setup in my SF org but not when I'm trying to use it in heroku.